# Read & Write Struct containing Linked List in separate files in C

Tags: c, file, serialization, data-structures, deserialization

I have a concept question regarding Reading & Writing 2 different data structures(one of them is a linked list) in two seperate files (both files are binary files [.bin])

Pseudo of the data types:

```
Customer Data structure (to be saved on Customer.bin):
    Variable            Type    Remarks
    Name                %s[100]
    Id num              %s[15]  alphanumeric
    Address             %s[200] 
    DoB                 %s[10]  YYYY/MM/DD
    Purchase History    STRUCT  Pointer to Head node of Purchases

Purchase-content Data structure (to be used by Purchases Node):
    Variabel            Type    Remarks
    Date                %s[10]  YYYY/MM/DD
    StoreID             %s[10]  XXXXXXXXXX

Purchases Node structure (to be saved on TransactionHistory.bin)
    Variable            Type             Remarks
    Data                Purchase-content
    Next                *Purchases       Pointer to next node
```

Each Customer will have a history of their purchases, thus Each Customer Data structure will have a pointer to the head of a Purchases linked list.

If I have multiple customers and I want to 2 files; 1 to store all of my Customers and their information and 1 to store every purchases of every customer, how can I read/write if i want to print all information of a customer and their purchase history?

I can't wrap my head around the logic of connecting the data on for a program which will use these data accordingly (connecting customer data with their own purchases data). Do pointers even work in files? especially if we seperate the pointer and the data its pointing to different files.

Is there a better way to store the data or a better concept to do this? (I want to keep number of files to a minimum) (I am not allowed to use any database softwares, can only do all things through a single c script)

Any enlightenment would be highly appreciated.

Comment: No, pointers definetely do not work when reading/writing to file as those addresses are not valid outside the process. What you are needing to do is called "serialisation" (to help you in searching). If you want it in seperate files then you can use a key to link customer data with purchase data. For example, store the customer id with each purchase data. There are many other alternatives.

Comment: No, pointers don't work in files. But you can convert into a format where the "pointers" are represented byt something else, like a unique id or similar. Or perhaps convert the list into an array, and convert the links (pointers) to indexes into this array. Then you could save the array pretty much as-is.

Comment: You can simply use comma-separated values. If you want to get fancy, you can use something like XML or JSON, but comma-separated values are probably the simplest way to start. You will need to convert your data into a stream of bytes because files are streams of bytes. Any good textbook or "learn to program" documentation will have a section on serialization. That's the word to search for.

Comment: You can't store "linked lists" -- but you can store the nodes that make up the list. Reason -- the addresses for the pointers will change each time the program runs (address randomization, etc..). So it you were using the binary route, you would simply write out the number of nodes in the list followed by the nodes. To read the data back it, you would read the number of nodes and then loop adding that many nodes to your list. (note this works with the same compiler -- but not between compilers due to padding bytes). The other alternative is a .csv @DavidSchwartz suggests. (more portable)

Comment: The structure in your files cannot be the same as it is in Memory. The pointers in your structures will most likely be invalid after loading them. You need to create your own references (perhaps uuids). Then you can store an array of users in one file. And an array of purchases in another. From the uuid references you can reconstruct your linked lists in memory after loading the arrays.

Comment: @everclear I generally would not worry about the pointers, they are just part of each node that get reset (rewired) when you read adding the node back to the list. The only downside is you are writing an extra 4/8-bytes for each node that doesn't contain anything useful.